# Setting datagrid columns headers

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, datagrid

I have a datagrid (from WPF Toolkit) which has some columns.

Columns headers are set from xaml.

Then from view code-behind, there are places where I do below:

```
MyDg.Columns[10].Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
```

So the problem with this is that when I remove or add some columns to the datagrid then I need to modify the index set in the above expression depending on if the column I remove or add is before that referenced in the above expression.

So I would like to write the above expression in some manner to avoid the dependency with datagrid columns addition or removal process.

For example defining some constants in view code-behind for headers and from the view (xaml) assing these constants to datagrid as header names. Then from view code behind I could find the index from the column header and proceed:

```
var index = dataGrid.Columns.Single(c => c.Header.ToString() == "HeaderName").DisplayIndex;

dataGrid.Columns[index].Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
```

I also have thought about binding a property from view code-behind to each datagrid column header but in the view code-behind constructor I set the datacontext to the view model.

So any idea on how to do this?

Comment: *"Columns headers are set from xaml"* I want to see the XAML. "*when I remove or add some columns*" Why, how, where, when? Is your approach with `dataGrid.Columns.Single(c => c.Header.ToString() == "HeaderName")` not working?

Comment: why don't you just set Column Visibility on xaml

Comment: @grek40 "When I remove or add some columns" I refer in design time, when for some reason I need to do some change. Then I need to modify code-behind as well. But it can occur that I forgot to modify code-behind. So to avoid this I need some way of centralize the process of setting column headers. In xaml I set columns header as below: <my:DataGridTextColumn Header="MyColumHeader" .. />

Comment: I agree with Rise... just set visibility in XAML, then it's all in one place.

Comment: @Rise Great! I will try. thanks!